# Add new lines using vertical select VIM

Tags: vim

Suppose we have the following file content opened in VIM:

```
function a1 {}
function a2 {}
function a3 {}
function a4 {}
function a5 {}
function a6 {}
function a7 {}
```

I want to expand all functions in this style:

```
function an {

}
```

For that, I tried to use a vertical select (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>):

```
function a1 {█
function a2 {█
function a3 {█
function a4 {█
function a5 {█
function a6 {█
function a7 {█
```

Then I pressed <kbd>I</kbd>. Then <kbd>Enter</kbd> (in insert mode):

```
function a1 {
}
function a2 {}
function a3 {}
function a4 {}
function a5 {}
function a6 {}
function a7 {}
```

Then I pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd>. I expected to expand all blocks. Nothing happened. Why?

I know that a simple replace or a macro would save me. I know that there are alternatives, but I want to know why *new line* was not added when using vertical select.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is not "vertical select", it is "blockwise-visual". As it's name implies, it is for selecting a "block" (rectangle) of text.

If you insert a line break inside the selected block, it disrupts everything that comes below it. The result is that there is no longer a meaningful way for Vim to apply changes to the rest of the block since it isn't clear what "the rest" is anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Like Max said, enter can not be inserted in blockwise-visual vim mode, documentation says:

*Visual-block change (v_b_c): All selected text in the block will be replaced by the same text string.  When using "c" the selected text is deleted and Insert mode started.  You can then
enter text **(without a line break)**.  When you hit , the same string is
inserted in all previously selected lines.*

The best workaround I found is:

- bitwise select column where you want to insert newline, example column 1x3:

  > <kbd>ctrl</kbd>Vjjj
- insert some mark that is unique in text block manipulated, example use mark "**NEWL**":

  > <kbd>shift</kbd>INEWL<kbd>esc</kbd>
- do line select of the block, example:

  > <kbd>shift</kbd>Vjjj
- do replace of the mark just inserted with newline (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> -> ^M), example:

  > :s/NEWL/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>v<kbd>enter</kbd>/g

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is apply a `:substitution` for the range of lines, e.g. addressing them through visual mode:

```
:'<,'>s/{}$/{\r\r}/
```

As Max has already answered, visual block inserting only works as long as you don't disrupt the block's layout by inserting additional lines (or moving around while editing).

Answer (score -1):

try using sed:

`:%!sed 's/}/\n\n}/g`

read to the bottom of your answer and realized you weren't looking for a workaround... i'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: Basically you don't answer my question. What I wrote in the end of my question is that I know that there are other solutions (like replace, macros and so on) to expand the blocks, but I want to know why this method doesn't work.

Comment: "read to the bottom of your answer and realized you weren't looking for a workaround... i'm not sure why it doesn't work."